# win32 C api call for disabling a network adapter?

Tags: windows, winapi

Ive been all over looking for a way to disable the network adapter through M$ IP Helper routines.

For the majority of the code I've been using this api:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366071(v=VS.85).aspx

However, I do not see a way to actually disable the adapters .. If deleting the IP address associated with the adapter disables the adapter I will accept that, but wasn't sure.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a simple API to disable it.  I think you might have to go through the device manager API.  SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty + SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS + CONFIGFLAG_DISABLED looks promising.

There are also some suggestions [here](http://www.gershnik.com/faq/manage.asp#enable).

Comment: Thanks luke I think ill look into those shell network interfaces. Unfortunately this is a porting limitation otherwise I'd use WMI