# Disable LAN connection

Tags: c#-4.0

My system is connected with a LAN connection.

I need to disable my LAN connection,

How could i do this using C# program

Can you help me please??

Comment: This question is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561199/win32-c-api-call-for-disabling-a-network-adapter You can't disable your LAN connection without doing a windows API call.

Comment: @icktoofay: I have a Connected three systems in LAN. I need to disconnect internet connection for a particular system when needed, I guess i could disconnect internet connection if i disable LAN connection. Can u help me??

Comment: @bleepzter: How could i make Windows API call, I am new to C#, can you please help??

Comment: Downvoting as it's been asked twice here and twice on SuperUser. I posted my answer below on SU before noticing this, otherwise I wouldn't have looked twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Shared Sub ToggleWirelessConnection()
    For Each verb As Shell32.FolderItemVerb In WirelessConnectionFolderItem.Verbs
        If verb.Name = "En&able" OrElse verb.Name = "Disa&ble" Then
            verb.DoIt()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

This is the code in VB and it works.

Answer (score 1):

As I've answered this over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/284529/how-to-disconnect-from-the-internet-connection-programatically) - just adding this here as it should only have been on SO:

You can disable/enable your NIC from the command line:

```
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” disabled
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” enabled
```

Replace "Local Area Connection" with the name of the Network Interface you want to disable.

You can call this from C# using something like the following:

#### Enable

```
static void Enable(string interfaceName)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = 
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" enable");
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();
}
```

#### Disable

```
static void Disable(string interfaceName)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = 
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" disable");
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks jaymz, I am new that's why!!

Comment: I should disable LAN, How could i find the interfacename.. is it like "\\admin\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=1"

Comment: I am not getting it, can you please help me. i am using windows XP. I need to disconnect the LAN  cable

Comment: The code to disable/enable an interface is there. What don't you get? If you need more questions answered, ask a new question **providing a clear explanation of what you're after**.

Comment: Thanks jayamz, I found a VB program that solves my puzzle, If i start a new question they are closing it.. Don't know why?