# .NET How to kill localhost connection programmatically for some testing

Tags: c#, .net, connection

I have some event that are triggered in my application when there are some connection problems (communicating with server), this feature should provide retry mechanism for my requests. Now I want to test this. It would be best solution if there were some C# library in which I can turn on and off my localhost connection at specific port. Is there a way to do this in .NET?

**EDIT:** I'm communicating with jetty server which is manually started at 8080 port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this might not be the answer you want, but I try anyhow.
If you want to (Unit-)Test things like networkconnection you should seperate the concerns and make the network-traffic it's own (or many) interfaces.
This way you can easily mock every behavior you want. It will be quicker, cleaner and better design this way.

To answer your direct question: I don't think that you can do this in .NET. But here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561199/76051).

Comment: This is WAY easier than anything I found.  +1 to you for a good answer and for thinking outside the box!

Comment: Yea, you are right when Unit testing is problem. But this is Integration testing of whole system. I just need way to simulate no connection or very very slow one. I want to have situation where I recieve error at first attempt but when I call my retry method it should pass.

Comment: Ok - maybe someone else has a better option. But IMHO a integration test with networkconnections (failing) can only be done real environment. Usually I go with the above mentioned and then do some extented real testing the way we used to do (run around, plug/unplug cables, disable WLAN acess point, etc. pp)

Comment: I think you're right about this. There is no other way but to do it in real environment.